# Add widget to extension

Tags: django, widget, feincms

Is it possible to add/use a widget to/for an extension?

```
def group(cls, admin_cls):

    cls.add_to_class('group',
        models.ManyToManyField(
            Group,
            widget=?????
          ))
```

I want to use Django's FilteredSelectMultiple for the many to many field.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you filtering for? If it's a static value, you can simply use the [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to) attribute to the ManyToManyField. E.g.

```
cls.add_to_class('group',
    models.ManyToManyField(
         Group,
         limit_choices_to={'name': 'Editors'},
    ))
```

If it's a dynamic value, you'd have to override the `formfield_for_dbfield` function of the admin class to return the field you like. Let me know if you need an example for that casse.